# PHP DateTime Object Not Assigning Unless Debugging

Tags: php, object, debugging

I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to figure out at all. I'm writing in PHP using PhpED on a WAMP server. As of now I have used many functions and classes of PHP and everything works as it should, except this:
I'm trying to assign a part of an object to a variable, if I debug and step through it without doing anything, it will work. If I don't run it in the debugger, or set it to break right after the assignment operation it will not assign the value. Here is the code I'm writing:

```
//create datetime object with starting time in h:i a format
$openSoon = new DateTime('8:00 am');

//subtract 15 minutes from time
$openSoon->sub(new DateInterval('PT15M')); //This returns full date with current time - 15 minutes

//My objective at this point is to get just the date portion out of the DateTime object which is the DateTime->date value

$res = $openSoon->date;
```

That last part where I assign $res is the part that doesn't work right. If I am debugging and step over it, $res is assigned the date value. If I debug it and set the break point for the line right after this, it does not assign anything even though if i look at my local variables in the window at the bottom it still says that the $openSoon->date is the full date and time, but $res is just equal to NULL.

Again this works great if I am debugging and stepping over one piece at a time. I've even added sleep(10) between every operation to even simulate the speed of slowly debugging it when running normally but that didn't do anything.

If anyone has seen this type of thing before let me know, I suspect maybe something corrupted on my WAMP server, but then again it does the same thing on the hosting I use (Dreamhost) so that eliminates WAMP or anything local with my PC. I'm happy to provide video showing any/all details that may need clarification. Thanks!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 7.1.9

Comment: There's a [bug in PHP versions prior to 7.0.5](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69587) but that wouldn't explain it here. Unless you are somehow incorrect about your PHP version.

Comment: I just did a echo phpinfo() and copied/pasted the first line here

Comment: use `$openSoon->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u')` instead. https://3v4l.org/ciuhF

Comment: Ok I did try $openSoon->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u') instead but unfortunately it is doing the same thing. It will work if I just step over with debugger, but running it straight just comes out assigned as NULL

Comment: Not sure what that is then, but you cant simply access `date` prop even know its there and public.. https://3v4l.org/dVTCH

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, yes that was it, you were right on the $openSoon->format part, I had just accidentally re-assigned the variable after doing that. That looks like the proper way to access the date part of a DateTime date. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

Comment: The part that really threw me off is that if using the debugger it actually worked accessing the date part of the datetime object directly! Why would it allow it in debugging but not normally? I don't know but thanks again for the help!